# Extracting subset from plot in Python, using SpanSelector

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code, I am trying to select only a portion of the plotted data by selecting an area on the plot. The selection works, but I cannot retrieve the selected data in the global scope even if I am using the `global` keyword inside the `onselect`  function. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
import os

for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        data = np.loadtxt(file)
del(file)

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

xx = np.empty(0, dtype=float)
yy = np.empty(0, dtype=float)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)

ax.plot(x, y, '-')
ax.set_title('Press left mouse button and drag')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
line2, = ax2.plot(x, y, '-')

def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)

    global xx
    thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
    xx=thisx
    
    global yy
    thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
    yy=thisy
    
    line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
    ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
    ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min()*0.9, thisy.max()*1.1)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    
span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True, rectprops=dict(alpha=0.2, facecolor='red'))

plt.show()
```

After selecting the data via GUI, the variables `xx` and `yy` are still empty. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can set the `xx` and `yy` variables as new attributes of the `onselect` function. For example, (based on the above code):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
import os

# some dummy data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)

ax.plot(x, y, '-')
ax.set_title('Press left mouse button and drag')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
line2, = ax2.plot(x, y, '-')

def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)

    thisx = x[indmin:indmax]
    onselect.xx = thisx  # set a xx attribute of onselect function

    thisy = y[indmin:indmax]
    onselect.yy = thisy  # set a yy attribute of onselect function

    line2.set_data(thisx, thisy)
    ax2.set_xlim(thisx[0], thisx[-1])
    ax2.set_ylim(thisy.min()*0.9, thisy.max()*1.1)
    fig.canvas.draw()

span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True, rectprops=dict(alpha=0.2, facecolor='red'))

plt.show()

# show the stored values (the onselect function is stored as an attribute
# called onselect in the SpanSelector class, and from that you can get the
# xx and yy attributes that were stored).
print(span.onselect.xx, span.onselect.yy)
```